# How to call non-static java method from c++?

Tags: java, android, c++

How I can call java method(non-static) from native(C++) code? I saw some examples on Internet ut don't understood exactly(it' dont works for me).

I trying something like this code:

java code:

```
public void displayInterstitial() {

            if(adView!=null)
            {

        if (adView.getVisibility() == AdView.VISIBLE) {
                adView.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        adView.setVisibility(AdView.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }

    }
```

C++ code:

```
// JNI OnLoad
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    g_JavaVM = vm;
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}

JNIEnv* MenuState::getJniEnv() {
    JavaVMAttachArgs attachArgs;
    attachArgs.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    //attachArgs.name = ">>>NativeThread__Any";
//  attachArgs.group = NULL;

    JNIEnv* env;
    if (g_JavaVM->AttachCurrentThread(&env, &attachArgs) != JNI_OK) {
        env = NULL;
    }

    return env;
}


void MenuState::displayInterstitial()
{

   JNIEnv *env = getJniEnv();

    jclass cls = env->FindClass("org/libsdl/app/SDLActivity");

  jmethodID dispin = env->GetMethodID(cls, "displayInterstitial", "()V");

     env->CallVoidMethod(obj, dispin);
}
```

Sorry for maybe duplicate question.
How i can get jobject(obj) for this line env->CallVoidMethod(obj, dispin); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to create the object in Java, then pass the handle with JNI.

If you want to create the object in C++ code, just get the class as you do, find the constructor < init > function, and use env->NewObject(...)